# spark csv datasoruce unable to write leading OR trailing contrl charector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

```
val value:String = "\u0001"+ "V1" + "\u0002"
val df  = Seq((value)).toDF("f1")
df.show
```

Now df is having proper value for field f1. But while writing using spark in build csv format with below code, the ^A, ^B characters are not showing in output.

```
df.write.format("csv").option("delimiter", "\t").option("codec", "bzip2").save("temp_out")
```

Here the temp_out output doesnot show any ^A, ^B chraracter for field f1

Looking forward some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If Spark's save operation is dropping certain characters, you'll notice that when you open the CSV file(s), those bytes are missing. First, take a look at the bytes in `value`:

```scala
value.getBytes()    # Array[Byte] = Array(1, 86, 49, 2)
```

`saveAsTextFile` has been around for a while, and is a bit more straightforward. If you can't get the CSV option to work, this is a good workaround.

```scala
df.rdd.map(_.mkString("\t")).saveAsTextFile("temp_out")
```

You'll probably still be able to read the file using the `csv` method from the reader, without any dropped characters, as below (but you'll want to confirm with your specific setup):

```scala
spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").csv("temp_out/").take(1)(0).getString(0).getBytes()
# result is Array[Byte] = Array(1, 86, 49, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks Elinda , Had changed my code as suggested and it worked fine. As this is a valid case the csv parser should have handle it, can we raise this issue in spark forum.